# Why does position of code affect performance in C++?

Tags: c++, performance

I am running a test performance, and found out that changing the order of the code makes it faster without compromising the result.

Performance is measured by time execution using *chrono* library.

```
vector< vector<float> > U(matrix_size, vector<float>(matrix_size,14));
vector< vector<float> > L(matrix_size, vector<float>(matrix_size,12));
vector< vector<float> > matrix_positive_definite(matrix_size, vector<float>(matrix_size,23));

for (i = 0; i < matrix_size; ++i) {         
   for(j= 0; j < matrix_size; ++j){
//Part II : ________________________________________
    float sum2=0;               
    for(k= 0; k <= (i-1); ++k){
      float sum2_temp=L[i][k]*U[k][j];
      sum2+=sum2_temp;
    }
//Part I : _____________________________________________
    float sum1=0;       
    for(k= 0; k <= (j-1); ++k){
      float sum1_temp=L[i][k]*U[k][j];
      sum1+=sum1_temp;
    }           
//__________________________________________
    if(i>j){
      L[i][j]=(matrix_positive_definite[i][j]-sum1)/U[j][j]; 
    }
    else{
       U[i][j]=matrix_positive_definite[i][j]-sum2;
    }   
   }
}
```

I compile with `g++ -O3` (GCC 7.4.0 in Intel i5/Win10).
I changed the order of Part I & Part II and got faster result if Part II executed before Part I. What's going on?

This is the [link](https://github.com/cho-uc/Matrix-Parallel-Programming/blob/master/performance_change_order_code.cpp) to the whole program.

Comment: How much faster?

Comment: What is the value of `matrix_size`?

Comment: 3 times faster, matrix_size >400. I will upload the whole file after I cleaned it up.

Comment: I kinda expect that -O3 should be able to know which order is preferable. The fact that there is a difference is odd. It could be somehow dependent to where exactly these "matrices" are allocated in memory (something to do with alignment). So you might randomly get that sometimes one version is faster and in some cases another. (P.S. don't use vector<vector> for representing matrices, it is a poor choice.)

Comment: Yes, this does happen. I have captured before and after code versions (where unexpected performance changes occur).  It is repeatable on my one computer ... unknown for any others.  IMHO, it is caused mostly by a desktop's hw's features.

Comment: I ran both versions with clang 7.0 and gcc 8.2 and found no differences at all in performance.

Comment: @ALX23z "I kinda expect that -O3 should be able to know which order is preferable." I don't think so... compilers are very smart... but not that smart yet I'm afraid... I'm pretty sure no compiler would switch part I and part II.

Comment: What is the type of `i`, `j`, `k` and `matrix_size`?

Comment: Btw, you do redundant work, you sum the part `0..min(i,j)` twice. And even, you throw away one of the `sum1`/`sum2`. I'd refactor this code first, to avoid unnecessary calculation. Maybe the compiler notices this in one of the versions, and not in the other.

Comment: Can you show the asm output of your compiler?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is working code and should be on codereview.stackexchange.com site

Comment: @MFnx from what I know modern intel compiler would even consider switching the `i j` for loops. Though, not sure if all others do.

Answer (score 6):

I would try running both versions with `perf stat -d <app>` and see where the difference of performance counters is.

When benchmarking you may like to fix the CPU frequency, so it doesn't affect your scores.

---

Aligning loops on a 32-byte boundary often increases performance by 8-30%. See [Causes of Performance Instability due to Code Placement in X86 - Zia Ansari, Intel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IX16gcX4vDQ) for more details.

Try compiling your code with `-O3 -falign-loops=32 -falign-functions=32 -march=native -mtune=native`.

Comment: I used `-O3 -march=native -mtune=native -falign-loops=32 -falign-functions=32` but still got the same result. The result is consistent (3-4 times faster) no matter when I compile it. But thank you nonetheless, the link you provide maybe can give me some insight.

Comment: @cho_uc I would try running both versions with `perf stat -d <app>` and see where the difference of performance counters is.

Answer (score 2):

Running `perf stat -ddd` while playing around with the provided program shows that the major difference between the two versions stands mainly in the prefetch.

```
part II -> part I   and   part I -> part II (original program)
   73,069,502      L1-dcache-prefetch-misses

part II -> part I   and   part II -> part I (only the efficient version)
   31,719,117      L1-dcache-prefetch-misses

part I -> part II   and   part I -> part II (only the less efficient version)
  114,520,949      L1-dcache-prefetch-misses
```

nb: according to the compiler explorer, `part II -> part I` is very similar to `part I -> part II`.

I guess that, on the first iterations over `i`, `part II` does almost nothing, but iterations over `j` make `part I` access `U[k][j]` according to a pattern that will ease prefetch for the next iterations over `i`.

Answer (score 1):

The faster version is similar to the performance you get when you move the loops inside the `if (i > j)`.

```
if (i > j) {
    float sum1 = 0;
    for (std::size_t k = 0; k < j; ++k){
        sum1 += L_series[i][k] * U_series[k][j];
    }
    L_parallel[i][j] = matrix_positive_definite[i][j] - sum1;
        L[i][j] /= U[j][j];
}
if (i <= j) {
    float sum2 = 0;
    for (std::size_t k = 0; k < i; ++k){
        sum2 += L_series[i][k] * U_series[k][j];
    }
    U_parallel[i][j] = matrix_positive_definite[i][j] - sum2;
}
```

So i would assume in one case the compiler is able to do that transformation itself. It only happens at `-O3` for me. (1950X, msys2/GCC 8.3.0, Win10)

I don’t know which optimization this is exactly and what conditions have to be met for it to apply. It’s none of the options [explicitly listed for -O3](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.3.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) (`-O2` + all of them is not enough). Apparently it already doesn’t do it when `std::size_t` instead of `int` is used for the loop counters.

Comment: Changing to `int` to `std::size_t`, `k <= (i-1)` to `k < i`, `k <= (j-1)` to `k < j` still gives me the same big gap in performance. But your answer may has given me an idea about why I have the strange performance. My guess is that the program behaves strangely when `i=0` or `j=0` because then we have `k=-1`.

Comment: @cho_uc i added my system specs, can you add yours to the question as well?

Comment: and it’s not `k = -1` but the condition `k <= -1`, but that didn’t have any effect for me

Comment: Done! I am using Cygwin GCC 7.4.0 in Intel i5/Win10 (and no parallelization)